# When and how CPL field changes?

Tags: linux-kernel, x86, cpu

The processor maintains current privilege level in CPL field. I want to know about all possible scenarios when CPL field changes from 3 to 0 and vice versa. For example, CPL field might change from 3 to 0 when a system call is invoked by a user process.

Moreover, please try to elaborate what goes on inside the kernel/CPU before CPL field is changed.

Note: I have read a few posts explaining how protection is enforced by the CPU using CPL, RPL and DPL. I am unable to understand when and how does the CPL change.

Comment: You want us to just cite reference manual about CPL field? Or what?

Answer (score 2):

This is a pretty in-depth question. The answer depends on which kernel you're looking at. Typically, CPL is only going to change during context switches (probably the initial switch from kernel to userspace) and during system calls.

The kernel needs to have usermode (CPL 3) segments set up in the Global Descriptor Table. Segment selectors (CS, DS, ES, FS, GS) are then set to the CPL=3 segment values.

Here is a great reference: http://duartes.org/gustavo/blog/post/cpu-rings-privilege-and-protection/

Also take a look at the Intel manuals. https://www-ssl.intel.com/content/www/us/en/processors/architectures-software-developer-manuals.html (Specifically Vol 3A, Page 5-7 is what you're looking for)

Comment: This is tagged linux-kernel.  Do you mean different Linux kernel versions or custom patches?  Or do you mean like amd64 vs. i386 kernels?  (32-bit kernels support vm86 mode...)

Comment: Ah, didn't notice the linux-kernel tag. I came here from the x86 tag (just joined SO today, forgive me). I suppose within linux, yes, the only difference would be between 64 and 32 bit. I'm not sure how much CPL change would be affected, because I believe segment descriptor tables are still used in x86_64, but I'd have to go back and check the Intel manuals. As far as other kernels, micro vs. monolithic would have some effect on when CPL changes occur, depending on what system processes are in userland vs kernel space.

Comment: Yeah, x86_64 still needs a GDT.  There are different entries for 32-bit user-space vs. 64-bit user-space, since long vs. compat mode, and the address size and so on is determined by the segment descriptor indexed by CS.  Welcome to SO, BTW :)